# AUTO INCREMENT char and integer in same column

Tags: sqlite

i have a table with an id as primary key

```
CREATE TABLE "societe" (
    "id"    INTEGER UNIQUE,
    "name"  TEXT,
    "phone" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

I want the "ID" to be auto increment but i want it in this format:

"C1", "C2", "C3", ...

any help please ?

Comment: Please read the tag info wiki for the tag you used ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ) and provide a MRE as described there. At least of "i have a table". Ideally of your best attempt to achieve what you want.

Comment: What will happen after C99?

Comment: The title seems to imply that you already know how to set up an autoincrement integer (i.e. without character as prefix). Please show that as a foundation in order to focus the question on the part you need help with.

Comment: @forpas C100,C101,C102

Comment: That seems a strangely inconsistent number formatting scheme. Leading zero until 99, then no leading zeros. It would surely be easier to achieve a consistent one, either leading zeros or not.

Comment: @Yunnosch edited !

Comment: Do not confuse the usage of the ID to uniquely identify a record, with a format used to display data. For identifying purpose, use a number only format. In the UI you can then prepend a "C" for display purpose.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes you can see this Q : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389089/sql-server-auto-increment-char-pk 
but the solution don't work on sqlite

Comment: See: [SQLite - Generated Columns](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/gencol.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use your auto increment `id` column to output according to desired output:

```sql
SELECT "C"||id from societe;
```

Which simply concatenates the desired character and the value from `id`column, with the help of the `||` concateneation operator.

After a few `insert` lines (missing from your mre), the output is:

```
C0
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5
C6
C7
C8
C9
C10
C11
```

e.g. here https://sqliteonline.com